# vuejs and jqueryui with browserify

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, laravel, vue.js

I use Laravel and Elixir.
I am trying to combine vuejs with jquery UI but it seems I am doing something wrong. 
This is my app.js:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
var $ = global.jQuery;
window.$ = $;
// load everything from jquery-ui
require('jquery-ui');

var Vue = require('vue');

var App = require('./app.vue')

Vue.config.debug = true;

var vm = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App },
});
```

and this app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul id="sortable" v-for="category in categories">
      <li>{{ category.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default  {
    data: function () {
      return {
        categories: [
          { id: 1 , name: "one"},
          { id: 2 , name: "two"},
          { id: 3 , name: "three"}
        ]
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
      $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
      $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    }
  }
</script>
```

I run gulp and it compiles fine, the console has no errors, But drag and drop are not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was stupid

```
v-for
```

goes to `<li>` not in `<ul>`.
So it is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul id="sortable">
      <li v-for="category in categories">
         {{ category.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```